# At what range will a pokemon show up?

Tags: pokemon-go

TLDR: If I'm standing still in Pokemon Go, how far can I catch a pokemon?

I want to start using this app at work https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pokemon-go-spawn-notifica/iklagoflgdhdicifcpjnlcjphibhebdo/related It will notify me when a Pokemon is near.

Thing is the 500m default range shows much more pokemon than I can catch without moving. (I can't move because I'm working)

So what should be the range I put in that application to have notifications only for pokemon who spawn and that I can catch without leaving work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4w34xy/eli5_how_the_70m_pokemon_scan_radius_works_and/), Pokemon will only appear if they are within 50 meters of you.

> You will see pokemon on in-game map when you are less than 50m away from him.

[This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4verfy/psa_scan_radius_was_changed_from_100m_to_70m_this/d5y6ywa) supports that number as well.

> Pokemon won't show up until the client decides you're 50m or less away from the Pokemon.

Answer (score -1):

40m officially. But since the game's distance measurement isn't so exact, you should set the app to ~60m.